# Alternative to database project in VS 2008 professional

Tags: visual-studio-2008

Is there an alternative to the Visual Studio 2008 Team System Edition - Database project (GDR professional) for Visual Studio 2008 Professional edition?

Or is it really one of the selling points for Team System edition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SQL tools from RedGate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql_bundles/sql_developer_bundle.htm)